# sha3 algorithm encryption and backtracking it

Tags: encryption, sha, sha-3

I have three questions:

Q1: Suppose I have a transaction ID in sequence order 1,2,3,4 so on and so forth. If I am using SHA3 algorithm on each of these transaction ID, Is there a way where I can figure out before the transaction ID gets encrypted, whether the numbers will be picked up in sequence (1,2,3,4 .. ) and get encrypted?

Q2: can I backtrack and see what transaction ID got encrypted ?

Q3: What type of characters are present in a hashcode?

Comment: SHA3 is **NOT** encryption, but hashing. Meaning it's one-way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms/4948393#4948393

Comment: Where does _'Q3'_ fit in __two__ questions?

Comment: AFAIK the SHA-3 specification still hasn't been finalized. So whatever you're using isn't guaranteed to be compatible with the final SHA-3 specification.

Comment: Your first question is very unclear. What is "picking up" the numbers? As ircmaxell indicates, hashing is one way. Also, if these are separate questions, ask them separately so future searchers can find them.

Comment: Q3: A hash outputs bytes, not characters. You could use an encoding like hex or Base64 to turn these bytes. It's that encoding which determines which characters are used, not the hash itself.